# vtkResliceCursorWidget rotate both axes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, 3d, vtk

I am using a vtkResliceCursorWidget in a VTK app, and I want setup a useful behavior: when I move a side (axe), I want to being moved both axes.

See the images from below:

Actual behavior:

[image: enter link description here]

Desired behavior:

[image: enter link description here]

I have found inside of vtkResliceCursorWidget representation, a method that fit my needs:

```
SetManipulationMode(vtkResliceCursorRepresentation::RotateBothAxes)
```

but the issue is that though I have used, it simply do nothing:

```
vtkResliceCursorRepresentation* pRep = reinterpret_cast<vtkResliceCursorRepresentation*>(resliceCursorWidget[1]->GetRepresentation());
pRep->SetManipulationMode(vtkResliceCursorRepresentation::RotateBothAxes);
```

where resliceCursorWidget is a vtkResliceCursorWidget, taken from here:
[Example](http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2012-July/075595.html)

Somwhow I expect of this, because on SetManipulation method remark write quite clear: "*INTERNAL - Do not use Set the manipulation mode. This is done by the widget*", even this method is a "public" method.

Could you guide me in order to able to move both axes (of vtkResliceCursorWidget) on the same time ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you also tried the public method `SetRepresentation(vtkResliceCursorRepresentation r*)` of the `vtkResliceCursorWidget` ?

Comment: Yes, I used pResliceCursorWidget->SetRepresentation(vtkResliceCursorThickLineRepresentation*); where vtkResliceCursorThickLineRepresentation is derived from vtkResliceCursorRepresentation.

Answer (score 1):

With the CTRL key as modifier, the behaviour will be as desired.

Comment: should be a comment